# Port problems when redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, redirect, https, port

We are migrating to Rails 3.2 from 2.3 and I encountered a problem with HTTPS to HTTP redirection. In one of our controllers, there's a single action that requires SSL, using:

```
force_ssl :only => [:action]
```

:action redirects to a different action which has to be in HTTP, with the original port of the application (e.g. 232323).

If I just use redirect_to :action_http, I get redirected in HTTPs. I ended up writing this:

```
redirect_to :action => 'action_http', :protocol => 'http://', :port => 232323
```

Which is rather clunky. Anyone has any idea how to do this properly?
Thank you.

Comment: Just for correctness: Ports range from 0 to 65535. There is no port 232323.

Comment: Just for the sake of the example :)